# How do I control the focus order for TextBoxes inside a html container

Tags: .net, angularjs, dom

i have two different containers, i want to navigate it in proper order like the screenshot. but when i tabbing last in the complete order it will goes to the search tab instead of going to the username and password text box, any thoughts of fixing this. im using of angular web page.

More over all the above parts are href# but the text boxes are wraps under span.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkLtr.png)

Comment: did you try setting up `tabindex` attribute on `input` element with proper desired index you want?

Comment: Im working on  accessibility issue and , its mentioned that you have to use tabindex=0 only. Yep for some parts it works perfectly, but for instance solution yes thats the ideal one.